# Need to change formatting

Tags: arrays, powershell, exchange-server

I have a script I am writing to gather mailbox sizes and put the output into a menu system for an interactive script that a user will leverage to create email accounts. I can accomplish my goal by writing this to an output file but I would rather pull the data dynamically on runtime rather than have to maintain an external output file.

```
   Name                                    Available New Mailbox Space             Database Size
   ----                                    ---------------------------             -------------
1) abc_2013                            66.16 MB (69,369,856 bytes)             320.3 GB (343,865,819,136 bytes)
2) abcPublicFolders1_2013               1.344 GB (1,442,611,200 bytes)          142.8 GB (153,276,645,376 bytes)
3) abcJournal1_2013                    42.08 GB (45,178,290,176 bytes)         48.13 GB (51,673,825,280 bytes)
4) abc3_2013                           30.7 MB (556,498,944 bytes)            204.9 GB (219,982,856,192 bytes)
5) Abc1_2013                           13.7 MB (643,497,984 bytes)            186.1 GB (199,850,196,992 bytes)
6) Abc2500_2013                        28.09 MB (29,458,432 bytes)             896 MB (939,524,096 bytes)
7) ABC2_2013                           27.7 MB (238,714,880 bytes)            100 GB (107,374,182,400 bytes)


$MailboxDatabases = Get-MailboxDatabase -Status | Select @{ Label=”Name”; Expression={$_.Name} }, @{ Label=”Available New Mailbox Space”; Expression={$_.AvailableNewMailboxSpace} }, @{ Label=”Database Size”; Expression={$_.DatabaseSize} } -Skip 1 | Sort-Object AvailableNewMailboxSpace -Descending
$Count = 0
ForEach ($MailboxDatabase in $MailboxDatabases) { $Count++; Write-Host $Count")" $MailboxDatabase | Format-Table --HideTableHeaders }
```

Instead I am getting the following

```
1) @{Name=Abc4_2013; Available New Mailbox Space=66.16 MB (69,369,856 bytes); Database Size=320.3 GB (343,865,819,136
 bytes)}
2) @{Name=abcPublicFolders1_2013; Available New Mailbox Space=1.344 GB (1,442,611,200 bytes); Database Size=142.8 GB (153,2
76,645,376 bytes)}
3) @{Name=abcJournal1_2013; Available New Mailbox Space=42.08 GB (45,178,290,176 bytes); Database Size=48.13 GB (51,673,825
,280 bytes)}
4) @{Name=Abc3_2013; Available New Mailbox Space=530.7 MB (556,498,944 bytes); Database Size=204.9 GB (219,982,856,19
2 bytes)}
5) @{Name=Abc1_2013; Available New Mailbox Space=613.7 MB (643,497,984 bytes); Database Size=186.1 GB (199,850,196,99
2 bytes)}
6) @{Name=AbcRoom2500_2013; Available New Mailbox Space=28.09 MB (29,458,432 bytes); Database Size=896 MB (939,524,096 byte
s)}
7) @{Name=Abc2_2013; Available New Mailbox Space=227.7 MB (238,714,880 bytes); Database Size=100 GB (107,374,182,400
bytes)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why using `Format-Table` for this? You can access any property using `$($MailboxDatabase.PropertyName)` in `Write-Host`. So if you want to have

```
 1) DB Abc4_2013 with available new mailbox space 66 MB and size 320 GB
```

You'd have to use

```
Write-Host "$Count) $($MailboxDatabase.Name)  with available new mailbox space $($MailboxDatabase.AvailableNewMailboxSpace.ToMB()) MB and size $($MailboxDatabase.DatabaseSize.ToGB()) GB"
```

You can drop custom expressions from `Get-MailboxDatabase` line and use this:

```
$MailboxDatabases = Get-MailboxDatabase -Status | Select Name, AvailableNewMailboxSpace, DatabaseSize | Sort-Object AvailableNewMailboxSpace -Descending
```

Additional resources:

- [article about size formatting](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/evand/2006/09/07/byte-quantified-size-and-some-powershell-tricks/)